# D7 Mixed menu (entity and content translation)

Tags: drupal, menu, multilingual

In my main menu I have mostly links to nodes that are translated with entity translation, so one node with the fields translated. But I have two nodes which are translated with content translation, so each node is actually three seperate nodes (three languages). Now I don't know how to implement these content translated nodes in the hierarchy of the menu. To clarify, my menu should look like this:

Main Menu
-Menu Item 1 (entity translation)
-Menu Item 2 (content translation)
--Menu Item 2.1 (content translation)
--Menu Item 2.2 (entity translation)
-Menu Item 3 (entity translation)

My question is this, how do I make a menu item for items 2.1 and 2.2? Since item 2 is actually three seperate nodes I don't know what to configure as the parent of item 2.1 and 2.2.

Thanks, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to migrate the content-translated nodes into one with translations through ET?  Then you'd only have one system to worry about.